# setting up newsstand in-app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, newsstand-kit

I created a Newsstand App creating Mag+. All is pretty and works great, but the app was rejected for the reason of

```
"We found that your app has an associated free subscription, however, it does not include a mechanism for the user to sign up for the free subscription.
It is required to revise the app to include the mechanism to allow user to sign up for the free subscription."
```

So what are the exact steps to set up a free subscription?

Please DO NOT just copy an Apple link and say "go here," as none of what they write makes sense.

NOTE: this is using another service for the building process, so there's nothing I can do about the internal code in the app, just the itunesconnect settings.

THANKS ... *every time you help me you save a kitten!*

Comment: is your app is submitted from your own developer account or it is something handled by Mag+ ? If it helps, a free subscription IAP (In App Product) need to be created in iTunes (developer account) for your app just like any other IAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free subscription IAP (In App Product) need to be created in iTunes (developer account) for your app just like any other IAP and there must be an option in app from where user can see that subscription and select to subscribe.

It seems like there is no option (like a button "Subscribe for Free" etc) in your App to subscribe to your magazine. Subscription availability is required by Apple for all Newsstand apps. On tapping Free subscription option (e.g. a button) a normal In App purchase (though free) should happen.

Comment: But WHERE is this option???

Comment: @SnowboardBruin you need to add an option in your app for users to subscribe. I am not sure how in Mag+ you can specify this but ideally it should be handled by Mag+ automatically. For Newsstand apps there *must* be an option provided in app for users to subscribe. This is one of the biggest problem with Mag+ (and similar) companies that they off load iTunes management responsibility onto users and just create app for them.

Comment: THANKS!! I didn't realize it was something I had to hook up through the 3rd party...I thought it was something through iTunesConnect!